# Как получить прямую ссылку на .mp3 файл, залитый на google drive?

Tags: алгоритм, google-drive

Нужен алгоритм получения прямой ссылки на файл, а именно .mp3 залитый на google drive. Ссылка нужна такого вида: http://google.com/my_file.mp3

Если кто-то может превосходно выследить происхождение файла, помогите пожалуйста. Это нужно для сервиса, а google drive хочу использовать как файловое хранилище.

Answer (score 3):

Ну [тут же](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads) всё написано и даны библиотеки под многие платформы:

To download files, you'll need to make two authorized HTTP GET requests:

- First, retrieve the appropriate
     download URL provided in the file's
     metadata.
- Then, retrieve the actual
     file content (or link) using the
     download URL.

Comment: Нужна именно прямая, такого вида: http://google.com/my_file.mp3

Такая ссылка нужна чтобы вставить её в проигрыватель. Если вставлять ссылку в том формате в каком отдаёт гугл, то проигрыватель не проигрывает файлы.